# When I publish, the content of connectionStrings in Web.Release.config is not copied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I have a connectionString in `Web.Debug.config`, and another one, different, in `Web.Release.config`.

When I publish my project, the content of `Web.Release.config` does not appear in the `Web.config` published. Why?

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <!-- <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SalvaVidas-20130610104655;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SalvaVidas-20130610104655.mdf" /> -->
    </connectionStrings>
```

**Web.Debug.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyContext"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

**Web.Release.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyContext"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Server=ServerName;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you publishing in Debug mode ?

Comment: @hoang: nope, it is configured for Release.

Comment: Maybe you should show the content of your web.release.config and the corresponding part of your web.config

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using Web.debug.config / Web.release.config as transformation.

You need to do:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SalvaVidas;Server=ServerName;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
         xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The `xdt:Locator` entry will find an entry in your original `Web.config` by the `name` attribute, located in `connectionString > add`. The `xdt:Transform` will change the attributes to the one specified in your `Web.release/debug.config`.

However, this will not work in the current state of your Web.config because the connection string entry is commented out. If you leave it commented, you need to change the  `xdt:Transform` to `Insert`.

For more information on Web.config transforms, look at [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: (1) I need to put that in both debug/release.config? (2) So if I uncomment the default connectionString i dont need to do `Insert`?

Comment: @Fabricio Well, if your connection string is different, then yes. If you uncomment your `Web.config` entry, the two `xdt:..` will be needed for both of your debug and release entry, if you need to change it.

Comment: If I use `SetAttributes` "DefaultConnection" is not replaced by "MyContext". Insert it inserts though.

Comment: The xdt:locator will find the correct entry to replace by the name attribute. Change the name to DefaultConnection in your debug/release.config

Comment: Oh so I need change that DefaultConnection name.. :p But If I change it will find my Context?

Comment: @Fabricio There's two options. 1) Change the `Name` property in your original `Web.config` to `MyContext`. 2) Change the `Name` property in your `Web.release.config` and `Web.debug.config` to `DefaultConnection`. Either way, both entry must have the same name for the transformation to happen.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you don't have an xdt:Transform attribute.

You have a couple of options, but in this case, you'd most likely have to use in your Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyContext"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

the xdt:Transform attribute tells it that the tag is already there on the original Web.config file and that it just needs to replace all the attributes with the ones you provide, and the xdt:Locator tells it which setting attribute to identify the tag by. In this case, by connection string Name.

Since transforms only execute when you DEPLOY (not when you run the application), this means that you have to use xdt:Transform, because you still want the connection string to be there on the original web.config, and only transform/replace its attributes when deployed.

In some other transformation cases, you can use xdt:Transform=Insert, which means that a setting/entry is not on the original web.config and the transformation will insert it when deployed only.

Comment: what do you mean? can you show? I dont know these details yet.

Comment: As Simon pointed out, you need to uncomment your connection string on the original web.config because even though this would work if you only deploy, it won't work if you debug/run the application locally.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain in detail, Fabricio. Hope it helps.